# RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu, using Google Colab GPU environment

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm working with [this](https://github.com/lucidrains/DALLE-pytorch/blob/main/examples/rainbow_dalle.ipynb) notebook right now, using Google Colab GPU environment. When I execute the block containing the following code

```
with torch.no_grad():
    generated_images = vae.decode(generated_image_codes)
```

I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-56287126db2f> in <module>
      1 with torch.no_grad():
----> 2     generated_images = vae.decode(generated_image_codes)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2197         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
   2198         _no_grad_embedding_renorm_(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
-> 2199     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
   2200 
   2201 

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument index in method wrapper__index_select)
```

I tried to comment all the previous block and searched for solution in similar questions, but nothing helped to solve the problem. Can anyone give me help about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you executed the code blocks sequentially, both `generated_image_codes` and `vae` should be on the same device, i.e. CPU.

```
generated_image_codes = torch.cat(generated_image_codes, axis=0).cpu()
```

and

```
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
vae.cpu()
```

To double check, you can run

```
print(generated_image_codes.device)
print(next(vae.parameters()).device)
```

Expected outputs are

```
torch.device("cpu")
torch.device("cpu")
```